# Camel Junit debugging autowiring of EndpointInject which is null

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, apache-camel

Edit: This is resolved see below

Hi all fellow Camel Riders!

I am testing a camel route and trying to automatically wire in mock endpoints.

I attempting to use `@EndpointInject` but they are not initiated during the unit test. My mock endpoints are null in my `@Test` method.

The start of my test class:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = CamelSpringDelegatingTestContextLoader.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@DisableJmx(true)
@MockEndpoints("activemq*")
public class MyTest {
```

`MyTest.java` has an xml application context file that includes the basic camel context and other stuff.  Also it is loading a `@Configuration` bean spring class that injects other services, and wires accordingly.

I have the following fields that I would like to be injected and autowired

```
@Autowired
private CamelContext camelContext;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock://activemq:queue:b", context="camelContext")
protected MockEndpoint eventUpdatesQueue;

@Produce(uri = "activemq://queue:a?concurrentConsumers=10", context="camelContext")
protected ProducerTemplate testProducer;
```

The `camelContext` is autowiring properly, and I have printed out the endpoints keys and they are mocked out properly.  But `eventUpdatesQueue` and `testProducer` are `null`.

I have resorted to writing code to instantiate everything, which is working fine:

```
eventUpdatesQueue = camelContext.getEndpoint("mock://activemq:queue:a", MockEndpoint.class);
Endpoint testProducer = camelContext.getEndpoint("activemq:queue:b?concurrentConsumers=1");

eventUpdatesQueue.expectedMessageCount(1);

Producer producer = testProducer.createProducer();
Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(camelContext);

exchange.getIn().setBody(body());
producer.process(exchange);
eventUpdatesQueue.assertIsSatisfied();
```

Which is working fine, but is tons more code then if `@EndpointInject` would work as I am expecting it to.

How do I go about debugging this?  How do I get the mock endpoints and producer to be instantiated properly when I test?  I am assuming that `@EndpointInject` would set the proper endpoint values magically for me.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: This is resolved ... see notes

Comment: context="camelContext" is used to refer to a specific CamelContext by its name, such as when you have 2+ or more. So if you only have 1 CamelContext then do not use it, or if you do, make sure the name matches.

Comment: Thanks Claus! Btw the new rest stuff looks cool, excited to use it when it goes ga.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: Done - added my own comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So simple, but yet so hard.  My `camelContext` was not named.

Broken:

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock://activemq:queue:b", context="camelContext")
protected MockEndpoint eventUpdatesQueue;
```

Simply remove `context="camelContext"` and as Shelley wrote ... it's alive.

Fixed:

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock://activemq:queue:b")
protected MockEndpoint eventUpdatesQueue;
```